# Read text letter by letter without strings

Tags: c

What would the best way to go about reading the text from a user and then counting the letters from the next one by one?

For example, the user enters

Hello World

The program would record in an array that

{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

As the title says NO STRINGS!

In my attempts, I am trying to use the ascii table for a more efficient method instead of comparing each of the user inputs to every letter of the alphabet.

EDIT: how do i run a loop of all input string characters without using a string?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by, "reading the text from a user and then counting the letters from the next one by one"

Comment: If you are reading the entire string at once and then processing it, you will anyway be going through all the characters in the string

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to compare each user input to every letter of the alphabet.
All you need to do is create an array of size 26 for the 26 English characters( assuming you only use upper case characters). Keep all the initial array elements equal to 0. Run a loop for all the input string characters and subtract 65 from ASCII value of that character which will give you the location of that character in the array and increment its value by 1.
[image]

Comment: how do i run a loop of all input string characters without using a string?

Comment: I could have provided you the code in the first place, but I want you to think of various ways to store the input and accordingly try to figure out the solution to your question :) This way you will get a chance to know a little bit more than what you aspire for :)

Comment: I figure it out a bit ago, just can't get it to work with the bigger program, it doesn't stop to wait for the user input...but like I tested it outside the program and it works fine

Comment: Please refer to the documentation [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Comment: ughhhhh, i get it working in a single main function, but as soon as I split it into different functions it breaks.... now this is just me venting...

Comment: Using scanf if I put whitespace before my %c then it waits but hitting enter doesn't make it continue, if I don't leave the whitespace then it just skips over....

Answer (score 0):

You can have array of 26 integers and increment the respective ASCII index.

**Example:**

```
int counter[26];
char buffer[256];

fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);

for(int i=0;i<strlen(buffer);i++)
{
   if (buffer[i]>='A' && buffer[i]<='Z')
       counter[buffer[i]-'A']++;
   else if (buffer[i]>='a' && buffer[i]<='z')
       counter[buffer[i]-'a']++;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the counter be initialized?

Comment: `65` and `'A'` should not be mixed since they mean the same in this program.

Comment: The title says "without strings"; `fgets` is a string function.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use a frequency table, which stores how often each character appears in the input. This happens in the first part of the below code.

In the second half, the code prints how often each of the interesting characters appears. This part does NOT assume that the letters appear in a single block in the character set. Therefore it also works on EBCDIC computers. It calculates the sum of the uppercase and lowercase frequencies and outputs that.

```
#include <studio.h>

int main(void) {

    int freq[256] = {0};    // initializes the whole array to 0; only works with 0

    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        freq[ch]++;
    }

    const char *upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const char *lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; upper[i] != '\0') {
        fprintf("character %c appears %5d times\n",
            upper[i],
            freq[upper[i]] + freq[lower[i]]);
    }
}
```